# decoded ogg file and change and write opus file

Tags: go

I'm trying to read a music file with the .ogg extension and make changes and save it, but I'm not able to save the file and make it play with same content from decoded file

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "testing"

    "github.com/jfreymuth/oggvorbis"
    _ "github.com/jfreymuth/oggvorbis"
)
    func TestSound(t *testing.T) {
        oggSound, err := os.Open("audio1.oga")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            t.Fatal(err)
        }
    
        reader := io.Reader(oggSound)
        decoded, _, err := oggvorbis.ReadAll(reader)
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatal("decoding error: ", err)
        }
    
        output, err := os.Create("output.oga")
    
        _, err = output.Write(float32ToByte(decoded))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("error: ", err)
        }
    
        err = output.Sync()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("error: ", err)
        }
    }
    
    func float32ToByte(f []float32) []byte {
        var buf bytes.Buffer
        for _, value := range f {
            err := binary.Write(&buf, binary.BigEndian, value)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("binary.Write failed:", err)
            }
        }
        return buf.Bytes()
    }
```

I can't read and write the same file with ext .ogg.

Comment: You are writing he decoded bytes, you are not encoding the data stream

Comment: @BurakSerdar can u help me with this ?

Comment: You have to use an encoder to write the result if you want to play it back, Read the package docs.